# BigQuery SQL: How to fetch respective sales from other table w.r.t value matching from one table with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, procedure

Have got two Bigquery tables,

**Table 1:**

```
store   article  sales
11      aa       14.5
11      bb       10.0
12      aa
12      bb
12      cc
13      aa       12.0
13      bb       11.4
13      dd       12.5
```

**Table 2:**

```
store   status      likestore
11      Active      
12      New         13
13      New
```

**Scenario:**
If tab2.status = 'New' and tab1.sales IS NULL for that store then assign sales of tab2.likestore for that store.

**Tried Out:**

```
select *,
    case when tab2.status = 'New' and tab1.sales IS NULL then <to add other conditions explained in Scenario>
    from tab1
    left join tab2 on tab2.store = tab1.store
```

**Final Result:**

```
store   article  sales
11      aa       14.5
11      bb       10.0
12      aa       12.0
12      bb       11.4
12      cc
13      aa       12.0
13      bb       11.4
13      dd       12.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Hmmm . . . Assuming one row per store then use `left join`:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t1.sales, tt1.sales) as imputed_sales
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.store = t2.store and t2.status = 'New' left join
     table1 tt1
     on tt1.store = t2.likestore;
```

Note:  This assumes that `''` really means `NULL`.  An empty string does not make sense for what should be a number column.  But if you are mistakenly storing numbers as strings, you can use `case` instead of `coalesce()`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But as you have mentioned, have now edited the table content at Store-Article level. Kindly let me know how your solution can be changed w.r.t this

Comment: Can you provide a solution for the current version of question. That might help me a lot. Thank You!